# spec files keeps failing, the error says "Cannot configure the test module when the test module has already been instantiated."

Tags: angularjs, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

i'm writing some test for all the components and services of a project not writen by me.
I wrote 160 tests and just 20 of them returns success, i do not understand the differences between the test that fails and the ones thet don't fails, i'm pretty sure that the ones that fails should not, becouse the webapp works propertly.
all the failing tests returns the same error(that makes me think i have some wrong config), the error is:

> Error: Cannot configure the test module when the test module has already been instantiated. Make sure you are not using `inject` before `R3TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

i know that's not the first question abotu this error, but the solutions i found online does not helps me out.

here is the spec file of a very very simple service:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { XService } from './X.service';

describe('XService', () => {
  let service: XService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(XService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

(i have spec files way more complex than this, and some of them are asyncronous, and like this one, they fails with the error on top)

here is a .spec of a minimal component:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { XComponent } from './X.component';

describe('XComponent', () => {
  let component: XComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<XComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ XComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(XComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

my test.ts:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing'

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: {
  context(path: string, deep?: boolean, filter?: RegExp): {
    keys(): string[];
    <T>(id: string): T;
  };
};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.

const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

COMPLETE LOG OF THE ERROR:

> Chrome Headless 99.0.4844.51 (Windows 10) MenuComponent should create
> FAILED
> Error: Cannot configure the test module when the test module has already been instantiated. Make sure you are not using `inject`
> before `R3TestBed.configureTestingModule`.
> at TestBedRender3.assertNotInstantiated (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/testing.js:1757:1)
> at TestBedRender3.configureTestingModule (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/testing.js:1663:1)
> at Function.configureTestingModule (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/testing.js:1553:1)
> at UserContext. (projects/lazio/src/app/components/menu/menu.component.spec.ts:22:11)
> at Generator.next ()
> at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
> at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
> at node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:32:1
> at new ZoneAwarePromise (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:1387:1)
> at UserContext. (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:21:1)
> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[UtilService -> TranslateService ->
> TranslateService]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateService!
> error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'UtilService', 'TranslateService', 'TranslateService' ] })
> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[UtilService -> TranslateService ->
> TranslateService]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateService!
> at NullInjector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11081:1)
> at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11247:1)
> at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11247:1)
> at injectInjectorOnly (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:4728:1)
> at ɵɵinject (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:4732:1)
> at Object.UtilService_Factory [as factory] (ng:///UtilService/ɵfac.js:4:39)
> at R3Injector.hydrate (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11416:1)
> at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11236:1)
> at NgModuleRef$1.get (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:25341:1)
> at Object.get (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:25055:1)
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'menu')
> at UserContext. (projects/lazio/src/app/components/menu/menu.component.spec.ts:43:32)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:301:43)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:371:1)
> at Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:134:1)
> at runInTestZone (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:581:38)
> at UserContext. (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:596:24)
> at 
> Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
> at 
> at UserContext. (projects/lazio/src/app/components/menu/menu.component.spec.ts:47:23)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:301:43)

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `providers` to the first `configureTestingModule`.

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { XService } from './X.service';

describe('XService', () => {
  let service: XService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [XService]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(XService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

In essence, do not have any empty object `configureTestingModule`s. Also, make sure you `await` all `TestBed.configureTestingModule({...}).compileComponents();` before doing any `TestBed.inject`.

The above may or may not fix it.

**Edit**
What I would do if I were you is change all `describe` to `xdescribe` and remove each `x` one by one (the x means skip). Once you have a failure, you know that test suite is problematic.

Comment: thank you for your help, but if i try doing this even just in one spec file, for some reason the 20 tests thet gave success suddently fails, how can i fix this?

Comment: What is the error message in which they fail? https://testing-angular.com/ This is a really good resource in learning Angular unit testing. Check out my edit on a good approach on how to fix or identify which tests are problematic.

Comment: i'm going to add to my question the complete log of the error, and i'll read the docs you 've sent me. do you see any problem in the log? in the second half o the log i read "no provider for tranlsateService" but if i insert translateService in providers the tests keeps failing anyways

Comment: Yes it is strange, sorry I am not sure what it could be.

Comment: thank you anyway, i didn't know about xdescribe